How to find the estimate of the correlation between Beta_1 hat and Beta_3 hat
I am studying multiple linear regression and am working on finding the estimate of the correlation between Beta_1 hat and Beta_3 hat.
Given the regression model y = B_0 + Beta_1x_1 + Beta_2x_2 + Beta_3*x_3 + error on 15 cases. We have the MSE s^2 = 3. We have
(X^T X)^(-1) =
[0.5   0.3   0.2   0.6]
[0.3   6.0   0.5   0.4]
[0.2   0.5   0.2   0.7]
[0.6   0.4   0.7   3.0]
I am looking for the estimation of the Corr(Beta_1 hat, Beta_3 hat). Please help as I am very lost on which formulas to use.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Is this work for some subject? It looks like a routine exercise as might be set for a class assignment or a test, at least it looks like a self-study question.
